# How do I copy part of a file to a new file?

Tags: python-3.x, text, readline

In Python I'd like to open a text file as `file`, and copy only part of the `file` to a new file. For example, I want to copy only part of the file, say between the line `EXAMPLE\n` and line `END\n`. So I want to delete everything before line `EXAMPLE\n` and everything after line `END\n`. How can I do that?

I can read the file using the following code, but how do I delete the

```
with open(r'filepath\myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    file = f.readlines()

<delete unwanted lines in file>

with open(r'filepath\newfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    f.writelines(file)
```

Comment: You can use split('\n') to return a list of each line, then use regex patterns to removes lines that fit the given pattern

Answer (score 1):

Create a new array and only add the lines you want to that array:

```
new_lines = []
found_example=False
found_end=False
for line in file:
    if line == "EXAMPLE\n": found_example=True
    if line == "END\n": found_end=True
    if found_example != found_end: new_lines.append(line)

file = new_lines
```

Now just write file to your file and you are done. Note that in your example you didn't open the file in write mode, so it would look more like this:

```
with open(r'filepath\newfile.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.writelines(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Read each line and notice whether it contains EXAMPLE or END. In the former case, set a flag to start outputting lines; in the latter, set the same flag to stop.

```
process = False
with open('myfile.txt') as f, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as g:
    for line in f:
        if line == 'EXAMPLE\n':
            process = True
        elif line == 'END\n':
            process = False
        else:
            pass
        if process:
            line = line.strip()
            print (line, file=g)
```